# What is the purpose of "recordsPath" in a webpack config?

Tags: webpack

I've read the documentation a bunch of times, but am still confused as to when I would want (or not want) to use a `recordsPath` entry in the webpack config. Could someone explain in more layman terms?

Also is the answer for the above different for webpack 1.x versus 2.x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Store/Load compiler state from/to a json file. This will result in
>   persistent ids of modules and chunks.
>
> An absolute path is expected. recordsPath is used for recordsInputPath
>   and recordsOutputPath if they left undefined.
>
> This is required, when using Hot Code Replacement between multiple
>   calls to the compiler.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#recordspath-recordsinputpath-recordsoutputpath

To give an example, suppose a simple app with the following structure:

```
./src
├── index.js
└── test.js
```

Where `./src/index.js` is:

```js
require('./test.js');
```

and `./src/test.js` is just an empty file.

Use [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) API to compile the file, e.g.

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

const webpackConfig = {
  entry: {
    'app': [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  recordsPath: path.resolve(__dirname, './recordsPath.json')
};

const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig, () => {});
```

It will generate `./recordsPath.json`:

```json
{
  "modules": {
    "byIdentifier": {
      "src/index.js": 0,
      "src/test.js": 1
    },
    "usedIds": {
      "0": 0,
      "1": 1
    }
  },
  "chunks": {
    "byName": {
      "app": 0
    },
    "byBlocks": {},
    "usedIds": {
      "0": 0
    }
  }
}
```

To understand a use case for module ids, you need to familiarise with how [webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack) bundles scripts. In the case of the above application, the output will be equivalent to:

```js
(function(modules) {
  // Module resolution logic.
  // Excluded for brevity.
})
([
  function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
    // ./index.js
    __webpack_require__(1);
  },
  function(module, exports) {
    // ./test.js
  }
]);
```

As you can see, internally, webpack is using IDs to refer to modules. `recordsPath` exposes those IDs.

Comment: I also discovered that this is necessary for LT caching when using with CommonChunksPlugin.

Comment: So, this will create a file inside my project in my local machine, which I then add to .gitignore and the like?

Comment: @RafaelEyng looks like recommendation is to check it in - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#recordspath